# Получение id автоматически созданного канала к видео в YouTube API

Tags: php, api

К некоторым видео, в частности к игровым, YouTube создает автоматически каналы. Нужно получить id канала, который был создан к данному видео. Пример: для видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK3aW2KBPEU автоматически был создан канал https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjFjb_7RG6LF0ckovlQuuQw/about

Прошу помочь получить id канала "UCjFjb_7RG6LF0ckovlQuuQw", если известно id видео "cK3aW2KBPEU"

Comment: Прочитай про парсер curl, загрузи html код и разбери его регуляркой там есть {"url":"/channel/UCjFjb_7RG6LF0ckovlQuuQw"

Comment: Да, это понятно, просто думал есть возможность через API все сделать.

Comment: отправляй гет запрос, с параметром, и выплёвывает результат либо на экран либо в базу

Comment: Ну так какой запрос отправлять, чтобы получить данные об канале, который был автоматически прикреплен к данному видео ?

Comment: тебе ссылку кто формирует? /watch?v=cK3aW2KBPEU

Comment: эта ссылка есть изначально, мне нужно получить ссылку на канал через API

Comment: Вы немного не поняли что нужно, нужно не выделить id с ссылки, а нужно имея ссылку на видео, получить ссылку на канал, который был автоматически создан ютубом к данному видео.